# How to grep a word after /summary/ in a variable and store the word in a new variable in bash script

Tags: shell-script, grep

I prompt user to input a path and stored in a variable named path.

```
$path: /a/b/c_12/d/e/summary/system/mode/output/file.txt
```

The structure of the path will always be the same, its just that the system, mode, output names are not fix. Therefore, im planning to grep the system name which located after /summary/.

How can i grep the system name and then stored in a variable so that i can used the variable using bash script? I am expecting to the system name should be in a new variable. (e.g. $systemname)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If up to "system" path structure is the same, then you can use `cut` for this task.
-d stands for delimeter, in your case it's '/'. While -f is needed to choose the cut piece.

```
cs-server@:~/$ systemname=$(echo "/a/b/c_12/d/e/summary/system/mode/output/file.txt" | cut -d'/' -f8)
cs-server@:~/$ echo $systemname
system
cs-server@:~/$
```

Comment: Hi, may i know what -f8 means?

Comment: @mmaz to put it simply, string is being cut into pieces by delimiter set with -d. Then you choose which piece you want to get returned. As in -f7 will return you "summary", while -f9 will return "mode"

Comment: @mmaz. Look at the man page for the `cut` utility.

Comment: Hi, this is my code, i tried on both but then error line 7: systemname: command not found.

#!bin/bash

echo "Enter the path:"
read path

#try1
systemname = $(echo "/a/b/c_12/d/e/summary/system/mode/output/file.txt" | cut -d'/' -f8)
echo $systemname

#try2
systemname = $(echo "$path" | cut -d'/' -f8)
echo $systemname

Comment: @mmaz Yours "systemname = $" should be "systemname=$", no spaces in variable declaration are needed. Also, strange you did not get an error on "#!bin/bash", I expect it to be more like "#!/bin/bash".

Comment: Hi, thanks @metamorphling !! it works well after i remove the spaces.

Comment: Hi, may i ask if in future the structure of $path still remains the same, but all the names are not fix, only /summary/ remains fix, is there any way to detect a word after /summary/ ?

Comment: @mmaz considering all the delimeters are still in place, 8th piece as before will be the one which goes after /summary/

Comment: sorry, i think i said it wrongly. what is the structure are not fix, means the system name can be at any places but its confirmed that it will be after/summary/ word

Comment: @mmaz `echo "${path#*/summary/}"` would give you the system name which comes after the word summary in the path variable.

Comment: @RakeshSharma. It actually gives `system/mode/output/file.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Use bash [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

```
$ path='/a/b/c_12/d/e/summary/system/mode/output/file.txt'
$ b=${path##/a/b/c_12/d/e/summary/}
$ echo $b
system/mode/output/file.txt
$ echo ${b%%/*}
system
$
```

See also:

[How do I do string manipulations in bash?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100)

[How can I use parameter expansion? How can I get substrings? How can I get a file without its extension, or get just a file's extension? What are some good ways to do basename and dirname?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073)

Comment: This is useful, but `b=${path##*/summary/}` is probably closer to the OP's requirements.

Comment: Also you shoud properly use double quotes around the argument to `echo`. It doesn't matter here, but there are nasty surprises when the file name contains whitespace or literal wildcard characters.

Answer (score 0):

Using Bash ERE support:

```
$ echo $FILE
/a/b/c_12/d/e/summary/system/mode/output/file.txt
$ [[ $FILE =~ (\/[a-zA-Z_0-9]*){7} ]]
$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]:1}
system
```

Given that the OP changed the requirements to: systen name can be anywhere but always after `summary`

```
$ echo $FILE
/a/b/c_12/d/e/f/g/summary/system/mode/output/file.txt
$ [[ $FILE =~ (*\/summary\/[a-zA-Z_0-9]*){1} ]]
$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]:9}
system
```

Answer (score 0):

AWK:

```
var1=$(echo '/a/b/c_12/d/e/summary/system/mode/output/file.txt' | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/";}{print $8}');echo $var1
```